# How to use a CfnParameter in AWS CDK without filling in the value at runtime

Tags: parameters, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have been attempting to use the AWS CDK to programmatically build a CloudFormation stack template, but am having trouble with using `CfnParameter`s to parameterize the template.

When I write a template manually in json/yaml, I declare `ParameterGroups` with nested `Parameters` lists, as well as defining the individual parameters including Type, Description, AllowedPattern, etc. Then in the definition of my resources, I can reference those parameters via `Ref` values, eg

```json
"CidrBlock": {
  "Ref": "MyVpcCidr"
}
```

**My question is how do I use this feature via the CDK, defining a parameter and referencing it later in the template?**

I have tried the following using `software.amazon.awscdk.core.CfnParameter`, but receive an error

```java
final CfnParameter myVpcCidrParameter =
    CfnParameter.Builder.create(this, "MyVpcCidr")
        .type("String")
        .description("The CIDR block for the VPC")
        .build();

final Vpc vpc =
    Vpc.Builder.create(this, "vpc")
        .cidr(myVpcCidrParameter.getValueAsString()) // <-- error on this line
        .enableDnsSupport(true)
        .enableDnsHostnames(true)
        .build();
...
```

The error states

> JsiiException: 'cidr' property must be a concrete CIDR string, got a Token

which seems reasonable because `myVpcCidrParameter.getValueAsString()` returns `"${Token[TOKEN.10]}"`.

However I don't see any other method on `CfnParameter` or the `Vpc.Builder` to allow me to use a parameter reference to specify the property value as a reference to my parameter.

What is the proper way to use the CDK to build a template with parameters and resources defined using those parameters?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574020/aws-cdk-any-way-to-pass-vpc-cidr-through-input-parameter

Comment: @gshpychka close, but not quite the same

Comment: @Paolo how so? Seems like the exact same question.

Comment: @gshpychka This question is clearer and defines the requirement in a better way. Also, none of the answer to the other question seem to answer what is asking here.

Comment: The top answer answers the question - you cannot do this with CfnParameters, and you shouldn't. It provides a canonical alternative.

Comment: You won't find a canonical answer, since the use of CfnParameters in CDK is discouraged.

Comment: @gshpychka Discouraged does not mean not possible

Comment: Sure, but it does mean non-canonical. It does seem impossible with the L2 construct at least, though.

Comment: To clarify - it doesn't seem that `cidr` accepts a reference in cloudformation. Has your experience been different?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `CfnParameters` looks correct however there are [known issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4096) when used with resources such as:

- VPCs
- Load balancers
- Load balancer targets

[Here's an explanation of why this occurs.](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4096#issuecomment-907807619)

A better alternative would be to use [CDK context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/context.html)

Here's your example updated using context:

```java
final String myVpcCidr = (String)this.getNode().tryGetContext("myVpcCidr");

final Vpc vpc =
    Vpc.Builder.create(this, "vpc")
        .cidr(myVpcCidr) // <-- Use context value
        .enableDnsSupport(true)
        .enableDnsHostnames(true)
        .build();
```

Similar to parameters, you can provide the context key/value via CLI:

```sh
cdk synth --context myVpcCidr=value MyStack
```

Context values can also be provided to your AWS CDK app in 5 other ways:

- Automatically from the current AWS account.
- In the project's cdk.context.json file.
- In the context key of the project's cdk.json file.
- In the context key of your ~/.cdk.json file.
- In your AWS CDK app using the construct.node.setContext() method.

See the [CDK context docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/context.html) for more info.